# How to perform an accuracy assessment for an image classification in Google Earth Engine when using the random forest classifier in probability mode?

Tags: google-earth-engine, image-classification

I would like to perform an accuracy assessment for an image classification in Google Earth Engine. I am using the random forest classifier in probability mode. I have come across an example whereby the accuracy is determined using the area under the ROC curve and have modified my code accordingly to try and recreate this output. However, I am unable to produce any result. I am unsure what the issue could be. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Also, if there are other accuracy metrics that could be used and included this would be helpful. I have provided the code below as well as a link (https://code.earthengine.google.com/79e1389e258647f35060044bb38e125e).

```
// Import Drone image and select bands of interest
var ROI = Swayimane
var ROI2 = ROI2

var image = ee.Image('users/shaedengokool/Original_UAV_image')
            .select('b5', 'b4', 'b3', 'b2', 'b1')
print(image, "drone_image")
Map.centerObject(image, 18)
Map.addLayer(image, {bands: ['b3', 'b2', 'b1'], max:0.3}, 'Original RGB')
Map.setOptions('HYBRID');

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------//

var addIndices = function(image) {
// NDVI 
    var NDVI = image.expression(
        "(NIR - RED) / (NIR + RED)",
        { RED: image.select("b3"),
          NIR: image.select("b5"),
        }).rename('NDVI');
        
// gNDVI
var gNDVI = image.expression(
        "(NIR - Green)/(NIR + Green)",
        { NIR: image.select("b5"),   
          Green: image.select("b2"),
          }).rename('gNDVI')
          
// NDVIre
var NDVIre = image.expression(
        "(NIR - Rededge) / (NIR + Rededge)",
        { NIR: image.select("b5"),   
          Rededge: image.select("b4"),
          }).rename('NDVIre')

// EVI 
var EVI = image.expression(
        "2.5*((NIR - Red)/(NIR + 6*Red -7.5*Blue + 1))", 
        { NIR: image.select("b5"),   
          Red: image.select("b3"),
          Blue: image.select("b1"),
          }).rename('EVI')
        

// SAVI
var SAVI = image.expression(
    '1.5*((NIR-RED)/(NIR+RED+0.5))',{
        'NIR':image.select('b5'),
        'RED':image.select('b3')
    }).rename('SAVI');
          

// SNIR
var SNIR = image.expression(
        "NIR/Red", 
        { NIR: image.select("b5"),   
          Red: image.select("b3"),
          }).rename('SNIR')
        
// SBRE
var SBRE = image.expression(
        "Blue/Rededge", 
        { Blue: image.select("b1"),   
          Rededge: image.select("b4"),
          }).rename('SBRE')
          
// SNRE
var SNRE = image.expression(
        "NIR/Rededge", 
        { NIR: image.select("b5"),   
          Rededge: image.select("b4"),
          }).rename('SNRE')

// GCI
var GCI = image.expression(
        "(NIR/Green)-1", 
        { NIR: image.select("b5"),   
          Green: image.select("b2"),
          }).rename('GCI')


return image.addBands(NDVI).addBands(gNDVI).addBands(NDVIre).addBands(EVI).addBands(SAVI).addBands(SNIR)
.addBands(SBRE).addBands(SNRE).addBands(GCI)};

// Map the function over the image collection
var image = addIndices(image);

// Print the result
print(image);

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------//

// Use this section of code to create the training and validation shapefiles
// Once this has been created once, this section of code does not have to be run again for future LULC maps
// Thereafter training and validation shapefiles can be imported directly


// Create training and validation data
// Add all training landcover classes of interest to one variable: LULC
var LULC = Buildings_Infrastructure.merge(Bareground).merge(Agriculture)
  .merge(Grassland).merge(Trees_Shrubs)
print(LULC.size(), 'original smaple size')
  
var referenceData = LULC
print(referenceData, 'referenceData')

var buildings = referenceData.filter(ee.Filter.eq("Id", 0))
var bare = referenceData.filter(ee.Filter.eq("Id", 1))
var agric = referenceData.filter(ee.Filter.eq("Id", 2))
var grass = referenceData.filter(ee.Filter.eq("Id", 3))
var trees = referenceData.filter(ee.Filter.eq("Id", 4))

// Setting agriculture to 1 and all other classes to 0
var setClass = function(feat){
  return feat.set("agriculture",1)
}
 
var setOther = function(feat){
  return feat.set("agriculture",0)
}

var agric = agric.map(setClass)
var other = buildings.map(setOther).merge(bare.map(setOther)).merge(grass.map(setOther)).merge(trees.map(setOther))
print(agric, 'agric')
print(other, 'other')

Map.addLayer(agric.draw("red"),{},"agric")
Map.addLayer(other.draw("blue"),{},"other")

var referenceData2 = other.merge(agric)
print(referenceData2, 'referenceData2')

// Create training data to run the classification
var bands = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5','NDVI', 'gNDVI','NDVIre', 'EVI', 
'SAVI', 'SNIR', 'SBRE', 'SNRE', 'GCI']
var training_data2 = image.select(bands).sampleRegions({
collection: referenceData2, 
  properties: ['agriculture'], 
  geometries: true,
  scale: 0.07
});
print(training_data2, "training_data2")

// Reserve some of the data for validation.
var withRandom = training_data2.randomColumn('random', 1)//1 is a random number generator for reproducability
var split = 0.7;  // Roughly 70% training, 30% validation.
var training_subset2 = withRandom.filter(ee.Filter.lt('random', split));
var validation_subset2 = withRandom.filter(ee.Filter.gte('random', split));

print(training_subset2, 'training_subset')
// // Map.addLayer(training_subset.style({color: 'black', fillColor: '00000000'}))
print(validation_subset2, 'validation_subset')
// // Map.addLayer(validation_subset.style({color: 'white', fillColor: '00000000'}))

var classifier2 = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(300).setOutputMode('PROBABILITY').train(training_subset2,"agriculture",bands);
var cropland_mask = image.classify(classifier2)
print(cropland_mask, "cropland_mask")

// Load palettes to use for displays
var palettes = require('users/gena/packages:palettes')
var vegPalette = palettes.kovesi.linear_bgy_10_95_c74[7].reverse()
// Create a binary mask for agriculture (1) and non-agriculture (0)
Map.addLayer(cropland_mask,{min:0,max:1,palette:vegPalette},"probabilistic classification")

var ROC_field = 'agriculture', ROC_min = 0, ROC_max = 1, ROC_steps = 100, ROC_points = validation_subset2

var ROC = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List.sequence(ROC_min, ROC_max, null, ROC_steps).map(function (cutoff) {
  var target_roc = ROC_points.filterMetadata('is_target','equals',1)
  // true-positive-rate, sensitivity  
  var TPR = ee.Number(target_roc.filterMetadata(ROC_field,'greater_than',cutoff).size()).divide(target_roc.size()) 
  var non_target_roc = ROC_points.filterMetadata('is_target','equals',0)
  // true-negative-rate, specificity  
  var TNR = ee.Number(non_target_roc.filterMetadata(ROC_field,'less_than',cutoff).size()).divide(non_target_roc.size()) 
  return ee.Feature(null,{cutoff: cutoff, TPR: TPR, TNR: TNR, FPR:TNR.subtract(1).multiply(-1),  dist:TPR.subtract(1).pow(2).add(TNR.subtract(1).pow(2)).sqrt()})
}))
// Use trapezoidal approximation for area under curve (AUC)
var X = ee.Array(ROC.aggregate_array('FPR')), 
    Y = ee.Array(ROC.aggregate_array('TPR')), 
    Xk_m_Xkm1 = X.slice(0,1).subtract(X.slice(0,0,-1)),
    Yk_p_Ykm1 = Y.slice(0,1).add(Y.slice(0,0,-1)),
    AUC = Xk_m_Xkm1.multiply(Yk_p_Ykm1).multiply(0.5).reduce('sum',[0]).abs().toList().get(0)
print(AUC,'Area under curve')
```